# Emotion styled components not applying rules

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

I'm trying to use `emotion`.

My .js code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { css } from '@emotion/core';

export const Menu = () => (

  <>
  <nav
    css={css`
      position: absolute;
      color: white;
    `}
  >
    <h1
      css={css`
        color: white;
      `}
    >
     Title
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Proyectos</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Acerca</li>
      <li>Contacto</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </>

);

export default Menu;
```

When inspecting the element, I get this instead:

*You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop).*

Comment: Are you using `@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop` (as documented in https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop)?

Comment: I just applied the `jsx` method since I didn't understood where to put those .babelrc or whatever file.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSX Pragma with jsx function from '@emotion/react'. This allow use css prop.

Docs: https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'
import { css } from '@emotion/core'

const App = () => (
  <nav
    css={css`
      position: absolute;
      color: white;
    `}
  >
    <h1
      css={css`
        color: white;
      `}
    >
      Title
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Proyectos</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Acerca</li>
      <li>Contacto</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
)
```